Find the $54$th derivative of a function at the point $x = 0$. Write the result in the form of multiplication.

Let's have the function $y = (x^2 + 2x) \cdot \sin\bigl(1.01x + \frac{\pi}{4}\bigr)$. Find the $54$th derivative of a function at the point $x = 0$. Write the result in the form of multiplication.

\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x^2 + 2x) \\
g(x) &= \sin\bigl(1.01x + \tfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr)
\end{align}
This is my idea, but how to manage signs in order to be correct. Of course my idea is derived from Leibniz rule for derivatives. We do not have to care about $54$th derivative at point $0$, because $f(x) = 0$
$$
y^{(54)} = \binom{54}{1} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{101}{100}\right)^{53} 
+ \binom{54}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{101}{100}\right)^{52} 
$$

What's your question? The expression for $y^{(54)}(0)$ looks correct. Do you want to factor the final expression and simplify it?

Assuming, I understood correctly what you are asking, you can keep track of the sign of $g^{(n)}$ using the sequence $s_k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. It has the property that two consecutive even terms follow two consecutive odd terms. To make it work in your case, you need to set $k=n+3$. Explicitly:
$$g^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}
(-1)^{\frac{(n+3)(n+4)}{2}}(\frac{101}{100})^n\sin(1.01x+\frac{\pi}{4}) & \text{$n$ is even}\\
(-1)^{\frac{(n+3)(n+4)}{2}}(\frac{101}{100})^n\cos(1.01x+\frac{\pi}{4}) & \text{$n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, $g^{(52)}(0)=(-1)^{1540}(\frac{101}{100})^{52}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=(\frac{101}{100})^{52} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$,
and $g^{(53)}(0)=(-1)^{1596}(\frac{101}{100})^{53}\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=(\frac{101}{100})^{53} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
